# dealing with liquibase upgrade that changed MySQL boolean type from tinyint to bit

Tags: liquibase

I'm trying to upgrade Liquibase from 2.0.5 to 3.2.2.  Liquibase 3.2.2 has changed the boolean type implementation for MySQL from tinytint(1) to bit(1).  This breaks a lot of our historical changesets, e.g. in places where we set the default like so: default="1" (which fails with error Data truncation: Data too long for column in MySQL 5.6.16).

Rather than rewrite/fix gobs of changeset history, I'm looking for an easier way to deal with it so we can upgrade. I'm not opposed to telling Liquibase to continue to use tinyint(1) for mysql. I see notes in the user forum on extending liquibase.database.typeconversion.core.MySQLTypeConverter to accomplish it, but that mechanism does not appear to be available in 3.2.2.

Any idea how I tell Liquibase 3.2.2 to continue to use tinyint(1)?  Failing that, any other ideas on how deal with this without rewriting changeset history?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

With 3.2.2, the TypeConverterLogic has moved to type-specific classes. So you can override liquibase.datatype.core.BooleanType and the toDatabaseDataType() method to return TINYINT(1) instead of BIT(1)

Comment: Is there any documentation on how to do that on the liquibase site? I haven't been able to find much, and I'd like to upgrade from an older version of Liquibase and ideally keep TINYINTs without having to convert all the old change sets. MySQL bit handling still makes these painful.